# How big can an Angular single-page-app grow?

Tags: angularjs, api, single-page-application

I have been developing a quite big web based application, using Angular 1.5.x and, amongst others, the awesome module ui.route, in order to simpify the single page application approach. I get all my stuff from a backend API, using RestAngular. Works really neat - so far. Not really that many 3rd party module beyond that, apart from ui.tree and momentjs.

My concerns are: how well will this work IRL? In some parts of the app, I have recordsets of around 1000 items. In other parts (meaning: different controllers in different modules) I have to add watchers for certain conditions to kick in. I have around 10 directives I use across the app. Every single part is its own module, controller and/or service, external html files as templates for the different routes. And a websockets connection that listens to incoming messages. Most models are basically divided into two parts: list the overview, and creste/update/delete an item. Some detail views are a bit more complex, eg they have nested items which are editable as well, must fetch additional information as everything is backed up by an id-based API.

To me, this is quite an app. With the test data, all's good. Is there something to be concerned about? Do I need to "clear" any memory once I leave a controller for another one, stuff like that.

Not sure if I expect a "yes" or "no" on this one, but one might have more experience in this field which could be a good-to-share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angular apps can be very big. The thing is, you don't have to show everything all at once, that's where the issues come in. Angular change detection works with something called watchers, which performs data comparisons at every digest loop. If you have 1000 elements on screen, it will check every single element at every digest cycle, which is pretty often. For modern browsers, the upper limit seems to be about 4000 items on screen, but think of it this way: people don't actually look at 4000 things on the screen at a time. So, most of the watchers aren't actually needed. Techniques such as pagination, and virtual repeat will drastically cut down on the demand angular places on the browser, and will let your app grow very very big. Clearing memory is usually not necessary. Modern browsers will let a web page take up as much memory as needed, I think up to 500MB with Google Chrome. As long as you keep your data structures well groomed, I doubt you'll ever run into trouble with memory.

Comment: Thank you! Pretty much as I did this, with the digest looping in mind, to show as little as possible, with the {{ ::vm.variable1 }} in mind where possible. But basically: if you go from one "page" to another, and by that change the controller, the old stuff will be "forgotten", not leading to some memory leak, even if it's a singe page app?

Comment: not sure what you mean - when you go from one page to another, the previous page's watchers are no longer needed so they are removed. The data may or may not still be around depending on how they're set up.